# Limit the number of records from SQL by certain requirement

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using oracle developer and I have the following query. The last thing I need to complete this query is because it brings up many instances of the same customer I only want to see one result per customer. Any thoughts

```
SELECT CUST_FNAME, CUST_LNAME, CUST_STREET, CUST_CITY, CUST_STATE, CUST_ZIP
FROM LGCUSTOMER,  LGBRAND , LGINVOICE
WHERE BRAND_NAME = 'FORESTERS BEST' 
AND lginvoice.INV_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('20110715','YYYYMMDD') AND            TO_DATE('20110731','YYYYMMDD')
ORDER BY CUST_STATE, CUST_LNAME, CUST_FNAME;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sico gave you part of the answer with select distinct.

The rest of it is to join your tables on matching fields.  Currently you are going to get every customer in the table, not just the ones who have bought a FORESTERS BEST product during that interval.  To fix it, change this:

```
FROM LGCUSTOMER,  LGBRAND , LGINVOICE
```

to something like this:

```
from lgcustomer join lginvoice using (something)
join lgbrand using (something else)
```

You'll have look at your database design to see what fields to join on.  By the way, the using keyword only works if the fieldname is the same in both tables.  Otherwise, you have to do it this way.

```
from lgcustomer join lginvoice on lgcustomer.fieldname = lginvoice.fieldname
etc
```

Answer (score 2):

Use SELECT DISTINCT to group rows into unique values